# Advanced WP_Query with meta_query, orderby?

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, order

I wonder if anyone can help me with this little complex query with ACF.

I have the following so far which should display:

- Pages,
- News Articles,
- About Articles and
- Involved Articles.
- Show: only 4.

Only display if: the ACF/Meta Key ‘home_page’ is selected ‘yes’

AND

Order by the numeric value of the ACF/Meta Key ‘home_order’ i/e 1,2,3 first, second, third etc

```
      $args = array(

                'post_type' => array( 'page', 'news-articles', 'about-articles’,'involved-articles' ),
                'showposts' => 4,
                'meta_query' => array(
                         'relation' => 'AND',
                             array(
                                                 'key' => 'home_page',
                                                 'value' => 'yes',
                                                 'compare' => 'IN',
                             ),
                                         array(

                                                 'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
                                                 'meta_key'  => 'home_order’,

                            ),
                 ),

            );
```

I think something is going wrong with the ‘compare’ and ‘relation'

Answer (score 3):

You should really read the [documentation on `meta_query`'s](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Here is what is allowed in a `meta_query`

- key (string) - Custom field key.
- value (string|array) - Custom field value. It can be an array only when compare is `'IN'`, `'NOT IN'`, `'BETWEEN'`, or `'NOT BETWEEN'`. You don't have to specify a value when using the `'EXISTS'` or `'NOT EXISTS'` comparisons in WordPress 3.9 and up.

  (Note: Due to bug #23268, value is required for `NOT EXISTS` comparisons to work correctly prior to 3.9. You must supply some string for the value parameter. An empty string or `NULL` will NOT work. However, any other string will do the trick and will NOT show up in your SQL when using `NOT EXISTS`. Need inspiration? How about 'bug #23268'.)
- compare (string) - Operator to test. Possible values are `'='`, `'!='`, `'>'`, `'>='`, `'<'`, `'<='`, `'LIKE'`, `'NOT LIKE'`, `'IN'`, `'NOT IN'`, `'BETWEEN'`, `'NOT BETWEEN'`, `'EXISTS'` and `'NOT EXISTS'`. Default value is `'='`.
- type (string) - Custom field type. Possible values are `'NUMERIC'`, `'BINARY'`, `'CHAR'`, `'DATE'`, `'DATETIME'`, `'DECIMAL'`, `'SIGNED'`, `'TIME'`, `'UNSIGNED'`. Default value is `'CHAR'`.

Your ordering needs to take place outside your `meta_query`. You can try the following

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => ['page', 'news-articles', 'about-articles', 'involved-articles'],
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'meta_key'       => 'home_order',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_query'     => [
        [
            'key'      => 'home_page',
            'value'    => 'yes',
        ]
    ],
];
```

Additional notes:

- As from PHP 5.4 you can use short array syntax, ie, you can use `[]` instead of `array()`. If you still running any version before PHP 5.6, you should seriously consider upgrading.
- `showposts` is dropped in favor of `posts_per_page`, so rather use `posts_per_page`

Comment: @birgire thanks, yes, it was a quick copy and paste error ;-)

Comment: Yes i read through all those but couldn’t understand it all fully to get it in the right order. I figured it out with some help from else where with the following..

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array(
                'posts_per_page'    => 4,
                'post_type' => array( 'page', 'news-articles', 'about-gorilla','involved' ),
                'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
                'meta_key'  => 'home_order',
                'order'     => 'ASC',
                'meta_query'    => array(
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'home_page',
                        'value'     => 'yes',
                        'compare'   => '=',
                    ),
                ),
            );
```

Comment: Please don't dump code as an answer, add some explanations to it, thanks. But this looks almost the same as the answer by @PieterGoosen, apart from the ordering. Note that `compare` is `=` by default